# object not found in lampp ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, php

am a newbie linux user.i have installed `xampp 1.8.3-2(lampp)`on `ubuntu13.10` and configured it.

i paste my `www`folder to ubuntu 13.10 in`/opt/lampp/htdocs.`

now the owner of `www` folder is root with create and delete files permission.i changed permission to `sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/www.`and i can access my old files inside `www` directory and results in viewing webpage in the browser url `localhost/xampp/www/xxx/abc.php` i can create files like `touch aaa.php`inside `www`but when i am tryin view `aaa.php` file its says

`Object not found`

`The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

`If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.`

`Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3` 
cannot execute new files and cannot view result of modified code on previous running code. any suggestions.

path `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/xxx/aaa.php`
thnx

Answer (score 0):

the path i was using was wrong.i was using `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/a.php` rather it should be `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www/a.php` that is why its cant be found. as i have url that responds in `http://localhost/xampp/www` so i had to just put my directories and files inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www` and it works fine.